# Showing jQuery calendar in a jquery dialog popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Does anyone know of a way to show a jQuery calendar in a jQuery dialog?  The calendar seems show behind the popup dialog.  I tried adjusting the z-index of the outmost calendar div, but it still didn't work.  The z-index of the overlay and the dialog is 1001 and 1002 respectively.

```
 $('#ui-datepicker-div').css('z-index', 1005);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allright, I figured it out.

```
 beforeShow: function(){
    $('#ui-datepicker-div').css('z-index', 2005);
 }
```